# How to protect checkout of code for multiple modules within a project using SVN

Tags: svn

We have several independent modules (e.g. mod1, mod2, mod3 ...) under a project 'proj1'. How to protect checkout of code for multiple modules within a project using SVN.

We would like to provide user1 access to proj1/mod1 and user2 to proj1/mod2 and .... Would this be possible or should I have to create  multiple projects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure SVN web access for different write permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948318/how-to-configure-svn-web-access-for-different-write-permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion was designed so that different people could work on the same projects.  Team updates coordinate the changes across multiple work environments.

In Subversion, you have to check out at a folder level.  You cannot check out an individual source module.  You would have to put mod1, mod2, mod3, etc. in separate folders.

Comment: the modules are in separate folders, I could specifically check out the code as svn co proj1/mod1 or svn co proj2/mod2 but I would like to restrict this based on a specific user (e.g. user1, user2 in this case). How do I do that?

Comment: That's not really a Subversion question.  That's an operating system permissions question.  You give user1 read and write access to proj1/mod1, user2 read and write access to proj1.mod2, etc.