# SVN read-only repository

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I work with Subversion and TortoiseSVN GUI. I need to block a repository (making it read-only) so that when I release a version no one can modify that repository. I create a new folder for every version I release.

Comment: How is SVN set up? apache2 + dav_svn?

Comment: Do you want to make it read-only AFTER you release?

Comment: Do you want to make repository read-only or a directory inside of it? The latter makes sense, the former is quite unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way, IMHO, to do that is to :

1. allow one person (or group, according to linux permission) to write in /tags path,
2. deny to other account (or group) to write there, but give them read permission
3. allow writing for everyone in /trunk and /branches.

Then, modify either pre-commit.pl script (see [Subversion Repositories: Governing Commit Permissons](https://web.archive.org/web/20130415141745/http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/usage/svn-govern-commit-permission.html), or modify access via Apache (here some examples : [How to configure SVN web access for different write permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948318/how-to-configure-svn-web-access-for-different-write-permissions)).

If you really want to tweak it easy, install a SVN Admin tool : [SVN admin management GUI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool)

In both cases, you won't be able to set tag in read only mode ...
Indeed, you might success writing a perl script, a post-commit HOOK, which will lock the tag, but I'm pretty sure that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use dedicated Subversion server + Apache2 + **?** or work just locally via *'file:///'*?

Subversion works with [Path-Based Authorization](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) and it's really easy to set authorization rights. BTW if your Subversion server has admin GUI I think the task can be done in a couple of clicks.