# Getting error 403 (forbidden) when trying to access newly setup svn directory (apache)

Tags: linux, apache, svn, ubuntu

I used the following guide to setup a SVN server on a machine with Ubuntu:

> [How to setup a Subversion (SVN) server on GNU/Linux - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60792/1380710)

However, when I try to browse the svn directory (`https://X.X.X.X/svn`) I get a "403 Forbidden" error.

In the `error.log` file I get the following two lines every time:

> Could not fetch resource information. [403, #0]
>
> (2)No such file or directory: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]

[Abatishchev had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948318/1380710) and he solved it by changing

`<Location /svn>` to `<Location /svn/>`

and [RedGlyph suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1948667/1380710) adding the line `RedirectMatch ^(/svn)$ $1/` to the configuration file.

None of these solutions changed anything for me though.

---

If I browse `https://X.X.X.X/` I'm allowed in without authorization and can browse a folder called `apache2-default` that contains the files `svnindex.css` and `svnindex.xsl` (which by [a Google search](https://www.google.dk/search?q=%22Index%20of%20/apache2-default%22%20%22svnindex.css%22%20%22svnindex.xsl%22) seems like standard)

---

The goal is to have a working SVN server with authorized read and write access, with only a single repository (although the configurations in the guide makes it compatible with more).

How can I setup apache to do this?

Comment: what do you have in httpd.conf?

Comment: Since you are setting up a new version control system, did you consider `git` instead of `svn` ? You really should consider `git` since it is more powerful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't really need powerful, I just need quick and easy, and since I already know TortoiseSVN I figured it was easier to use svn, if you still think differently, and know how I could setup git easiely on a linux machine, I'd be grateful to know.

Comment: @bahrep `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is empty. According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_Setup#.2Fetc.2Fhttpd.2Fconf.2Fhttpd.conf it says it should be located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but I don't have a `httpd` folder in `etc`. What should be in there?